# Proxy in CRA not successful

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy, create-react-app

I'm adding a backend to my app (cra typescript), which I serve on port 4000, so I added the line `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",` to package.json, like described [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually).

Next, I'm running code in my frontend app to hit the endpoint:

```
fetch('/hello')
  .then(res => { console.log('YEAH', res) })
  .catch(err => { console.warn('NOPE', err) })
```

But now the console says I'm still hitting port 3000 instead of 4000.

`App.tsx:6 GET http://localhost:3000/hello 500 (Internal Server Error)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console from your server?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, the console prints `localhost:3000` but the request is actually sent to the proxy, in my case `localhost:4000`. I would think (but correct me if I'm wrong) that for all the browser knows, the request *is* sent to localhost:3000, and that this is exactly what the proxy does.

I was getting an error because I simply didn't hit the right route, and was confused by the fact that I saw a log about localhost:3000